# Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: //input[@name='firstName']

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver(); 
Thread.sleep(3000); 
driver.get("https://www.google.com/gmail/about/"); 
driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(40,TimeUnit.SECONDS);     
//Clicking on Create account link
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@href='https://accounts.google.com/SignUp?service=mail&continue=http%3A%2F%2Fmail.google.com%2Fmail%2F%3Fpc%3Dcarousel-about-en']")).click(); 
driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(40,TimeUnit.SECONDS); 
Assert.assertTrue(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='firstName']")).isDisplayed());
```

> Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException:
>   Unable to locate element: //input[@name='firstName']

how to solve this?

Comment: Please add relevant HTML code

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your *xpath* might be wrong. Instead of:

```
//input[@name='firstName']
```

Try using:

```
//*[@id='firstName']
```

as the *xpath*.

- You can find the *xpath* on Chrome by going to Inspect Element, right clicking the element and choosing the `Copy XPath` option from the "Copy" sub-menu.

Answer (score 0):

It's timing issue, the form takes a second or two to load. You can add explicit wait to wait for it

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(WebDriverRefrence, 10);
WebElement firstName = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.name("firstName")));
Assert.assertTrue(firstName.isDisplayed());
```

Comment: I have tried using explicitwait ..Still throwing TimeoutException Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for presence of element located by: By.xpath: //*[id='firstName'] (tried for 15 second(s) with 500 MILLISECONDS interval)
 at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait.timeoutException(WebDriverWait.java:80)
 at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.until(FluentWait.java:232)
 at srcpkg.Registration.main(Registration.java:35)

Comment: @Pradeep `//*[id='firstName']` is not valid `xpath`. Use `//*[@id='firstName']` or `By.id("firstName")`